What is acpi specificlly?
Hi I'm having an issue diagnosing what's going on with my system.
I had a previous install that would not boot, I think a bad nvidia driver update was the original cause. I reinstalled and now I can boot into the system however if I leave acpi on I've noticed I have system instabilities. Programs crash randomly, sometimes programs won't launch unless I reboot, I get random sigvauls on bash scripts I run for work, and occasional lockups. If I set grub to launch with 'acpi=off' its all fine. However, I need this computer for work and it seems setting ACPI to off disables my ability to use all the threads on my CPU. What could the issue be? What is a possible fix?
Ubuntu 22.04.4

I9 14900K
202gb of ddr5 4800mhz ram (not running xmp due to ddr5 instabilities and issues)
RTX 4090 (currently not used on igpu seems drivers for the 4090 and 22.04.4 are having issues)
ROG STRIX Z790-E Gaming Wifi II (on latest bios rev just updated it to see if that
fixed acpi issues reset to defaults minus turning off secure boot)

